# ImageView aligned to the right side of parent in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When I run this code, the imageView is aligned to the right. I've tried adding gravity and such, but no succes.

I want the icon image (imageView) to be displayed on the left side, just before "Sound" text.

Any idea? Thank you very much.

```
protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context)
    {
        var cell = (SwitchCellView)base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
        cell.SetPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);

        var imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);

        cell.AddView(imageView, 50, 50);

        return cell;
    }
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCvSI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by writing

```
cell.AddView(imageView, 0);
```

... which will add the imageView to index 0 (to the left).